# unprecise math in R when dealing with infinite fractions

Tags: r, precision, fractions, infinity

The deviations of the mean should always sum up to 0.
However, when the mean has a lot of digits, maybe infinitely like this one which is 20/7, R fails to calculate it.

```
x <- c(1,2,2,3,3,4,5)
sum(x - mean(x))

[1] -4.440892e-16
```

I am quite a newbie and have not found any information about this so far, maybe I was not searching for the right terms.
Is it possible to calculate with infinitely long numbers in R?
I am asking this out of theoretical interest.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you have described is a general problem with all programming languages. Internally all floats are based on the IEEE754 convention. You can read more about it [here](https://floating-point-gui.de/formats/fp/).

As far as I know there is no easy way around these small errors, except for using number representations with higher precision.

EDIT: R already used the double precision representation of floating point numbers. To read more about it you can have a look at the [R FAQ](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50217954/double-precision-64-bit-representation-of-numeric-value-in-r-sign-exponent) SO question.

Answer (score 2):

- If you deal with rational numbers only, such as your example, you can use the **gmp** package.
- You can use the **Rmpfr** package to deal with numbers with an arbitrary precision (that you have to set).
- Another possibility is the **lazyNumbers** package, freshly released on CRAN:

```r
library(lazyNumbers)

# create a vector of lazy numbers
x <- lazyvec(c(1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5))
# compute its mean
m <- sum(x) / length(x)
# sum expected to be 0
y <- sum(x - m)
# convert it to double
as.double(y)
## 0
```